# Slow WiFi with Ubuntu 18.04 and Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168

Tags: networking, 18.04, intel-wireless

This is my story with an Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168 (M.2 2230) and Ubuntu Linux:

1. I decide to manually update Ubuntu **16.04** LTS, including the kernel/dist-upgrade thing.
2. Reboot.
3. No WiFi connection, `iwconfig` command returns no adapters.
4. While testing several reboots, I notice the wireless adapter sometimes appears and works.
5. I decide to install Ubuntu **18.04** LTS from scratch in another hard drive.
6. Boot live USB image (18.04.0 Desktop), go to desktop.
7. I try Internet connection, I notice WiFi is very slow, like ancient times.
8. I plug Ethernet cable and perform a minimal Ubuntu installation with last downloaded updates.
9. Reboot, unplug Ethernet cable.
10. I try Internet connection, WiFi is very slow.
11. I search for solutions, [I disable 802.11n (iwlwifi 11n_disable=1)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029723/slow-wifi-since-updating-to-18-04), WiFi works (connection speed is lower than 11Mbps), even after reboots.
12. Not satisfied with *solution*, I decide to ask here and [run Ubuntu forums network script](https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info).
13. Network script result is [HERE](https://pastebin.com/QJeSD2D6).

Related question threads I found:

- [Wireless Internet Issues - Intel Wireless, Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041277/wireless-internet-issues-intel-wireless-ubuntu-18-04)
- [Slow wifi since updating to 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029723/slow-wifi-since-updating-to-18-04)
- [iwlwifi Wifi Microcode SW error detected (Ubuntu 18.04 x64)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045466/iwlwifi-wifi-microcode-sw-error-detected-ubuntu-18-04-x64)
- [Wifi Issue with Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040762/wifi-issue-with-ubuntu-18-04)
- [Internet Connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047538/internet-connection)

Comment: Upvote/comment on a bug I filed with Intel here!! https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=200993

Comment: Take the firmaware from intel:
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html

Answer (score 3):

What I did to solve this issue is installing the latest stable kernel, according to kernel.org that is at the time of writing `4.17.13`.

I installed `ukuu`, the ubuntu kernel update utility using the ppa from "Tony George" (https://launchpad.net/~teejee2008/+archive/ubuntu/ppa):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ukuu
```

Then run ukuu either through the console (`ukuu --help`) or use the graphical version which can be found in the menu. Install the latest stable kernel and reboot.

**Warning**: There might be some issues; if they persist after a reboot, during the boot sequence, select your old kernel version (4.15 on my machine).

Answer (score 2):

**tldr;** Fix your drivers before you attempt to update your kernel.

My laptop has:

- Ubuntu 18.04 with xubuntu-desktop
- 32GB RAM
- 3TB HD
- 1070 GTX Cuda Core
- Intel 9560 Wireless AC + BT5

I too had no better than 3.8 Mbps connection speeds after completing the base installation of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

With ample support of a Linux Driver Engineer at Intel, [a solution](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=200993)! <-- Full Bugzilla Ticket.

I don't want to have to enumerate the steps comprehensively, but... don't update your kernel. Kernel updates have a nasty way of trouble-making. Besides, that's boiling the ocean. After all, your drivers are just not quite in the right state.

Instead, ***try this***:

1. Clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/linux-firmware.git/
2. Clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/backport-iwlwifi.git/
3. Install the latest driver on your system.

   ```
   $ cd backport-iwlwifi
   $ sudo make && make install
   # Fix any errors by installing any missing pkgs. Ignore warnings.
   # The system will tell you to reboot on success, DON'T ... yet.
   # Keep reading. Copy some firmware first! :)
   ```
4. **For Intel users**: Delete all the firmware files for your Intel wireless from `/lib/firmware/`. It will be all the `iwlwifi-*.ucode` files that must go. Copy them away if you feel like having a backup is wisest, so why the heck not?
5. Copy the newest firmware from the `linux-firmware` repo to your firmware directory (`/lib/firmware/`). These should also be `iwlwifi-*.ucode` files, like so:

   ```
   $ cd /path/to/linux-firmware
   $ sudo cp iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-38.ucode /lib/firmware/
   $ sudo cp iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-38.ucode /lib/firmware/
   # NOTE: I run a 9560 M.2 NIC, but you may not...
   ```
6. Now, reboot. You should be in business. You may run [speedtest.net](http://speedtest.net) and rejoice.

<3 and :)

Comment: I can confirm that this fixes the wifi speed issues on a Thinkpad X1 Carbon 5th gen running Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I've tried this approach and it doesn't work for me. If someone knows nice solution, here is my question: https://askubuntu.com/q/1088068/887142

Comment: Some of these issues are indeed fixed in later kernel versions and ukuu can be a help. I know that in my case, I have a custom lappy with a 1070 GTX card and I had to install Ubuntu Server first before manually installing xfce-desktop in order to get everything configured. It took me 4 times to get it "right" so mucking with the kernel was out of the question until I understood the root cause. *This approach is not for the faint of heart (or tired).* Thanks for sharing @MikeKaskun

Comment: Just a word of caution: I followed this procedure to the letter on a ThinkPad X1 Carbon 6th Gen and it hosed my Wi-Fi connection (adapter is no longer seen by the OS). Reinstalling latest kernel didn't help.

Comment: Turns out to be due to Secure Boot being enabled. I'll need to figure out which files were installed and sign them.