# Internet speed issues with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wireless, 18.04, internet

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on a laptop. I connected to a new WiFi network and am experiencing very slow internet. The same network on both a mobile phone and with the same laptop booted on Windows works perfectly fine.

In particular, if I run a speed test through Chrome/Firefox, I get a download speed of around 70 Mbps but an upload speed that starts around 3-5 Mbps and immediately drops to 0 Mbps.

The internet is fine if I switch to another WiFi network such as tethering through a mobile phone, which has always worked fine. Switching browsers does not help. Interestingly, running `speedtest-cli` gives both the download speed and upload speeds at ≈ 70 Mbps.

Please let me know what other information may help. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Add the output of `lspci -knn | grep -i net -A3` to your post  as plain text.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when updating from ubuntu 16.04 to ubuntu 18.04, I did the following to solve the issue :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ukuu
```

ukuu is for ubuntu kernel update utility 
After that you can run ukuu with a GUI to install the last stable kernel version

**Disclaimer** : I paraphrased this answer (https://askubuntu.com/a/1063311/863280) since I don't have enough rep to link it as a comment, but it resolved the issue I had

Comment: How should ukuu solve the OP's problem?

Comment: I had the same problem, and using ukuu to update to the last stable kernel solved it for me (well maybe read the answer I linked ?)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately doesn't work.

Comment: Well I am sorry this didn't work out for you, I wish you best luck.
TBH I'd like to know why my answer was downvoted, I know it's a poor answer which copy an existing answer, however I did give credits to the user who created the real answer plus as I said I don't have enough rep to post it as a comment... :(