# Help with .kernel_config_md5: Permission denied

Tags: networking, drivers, permissions

I could use some help.  I'm trying to fix my internet connectivity issues with this: [Slow WiFi with Ubuntu 18.04 and Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049307/slow-wifi-with-ubuntu-18-04-and-intel-dual-band-wireless-ac-3168/1063311#1063311)

Right now in above link fix, I'm at commands:

```
$ cd backport-iwlwifi
$ sudo make && make install
```

and it stopped here:

```
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 6 modules
/bin/bash: line 47: .kernel_config_md5: Permission denied

Makefile:40: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

Please help, I'm not sure how to get permission in the area I'm at, or how to continue.

Also, I'm not sure how to delete the files on step 4 of the above link.  I looked at them in the folder and there is no option to delete.

Comment: It should be `sudo make install`

Comment: Seems like you linked to the wrong answer. Should be this one, no? https://askubuntu.com/a/1071565/301745

Comment: ok thanks for help all... do you guys know how to do this in the above thread... "For Intel users: Delete all the firmware files for your Intel wireless from /lib/firmware/. It will be all the iwlwifi-*.ucode files that must go."  I copied the files away but can't delete them, and can't do a chown command to get ownership of them.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by following [this post on Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1217442&p=7642209#post7642209):

> ```
> make install
> sudo !!
>
> = sudo make install
> ```

Comment: You only need `sudo make install`. In the linked post, SuperSonic4 is just saying if you ran a command (`make install`) then realized you need `sudo` for it, `sudo !!` will re-run the command with `sudo`.