# How to undo the installation of backport-iwlwifi?

Tags: intel-wireless, iwlwifi

I cloned [backport-iwlwifi](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/backport-iwlwifi.git/) and ran `cd backport-iwlwifi && sudo make && make install`. Is there any way to undo this?

Comment: Try `cd backport-iwlwifi && make uninstall` Many well-behaved `Makefile`s have an `uninstall` target.

Comment: This is perfect, actually did the trick! Can you add it as an answer @waltinator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `cd backport-iwlwifi && make uninstall` Many well-behaved `Makefile`s have an `uninstall` target.