# 18.04LTS Wifi Intel AC9260 problems regression May 2020

Tags: 18.04, wireless, kernel, kubuntu, iwlwifi

Since a couple of days (May 2020) my Wifi Intel AC9260 causes big troubles on my Kubuntu 18.04LTS laptop.

Not sure which update exactly caused the problems, but Wifi is slow, and my cursor is stuttering. Disabling Wifi, or using a different WIfi USB adapter solves the problems.

Kernel:

```
 uname -a
 Linux 5.3.0-51-generic #44~18.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 23 14:27:18 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Wifi:

```
  lspci -kvnn | sed -n '/Network/,/^$/ p'

  3b:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260 [8086:2526] (rev 29)
  Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0014]
  Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
  Memory at dc100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
  Capabilities: <access denied>
  Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
  Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

dmesg:

```
iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: Collecting data: trigger 2 fired.
ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested   
iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
```

[Bug-report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe/+bug/1879452)
Cause update:`linux-firmware:amd64 (1.173.17, 1.173.18)`?

Any ideas for a workaround? Like up/downgrading the firmware manually? Tried to boot with a slightly older kernel in grub, but that did not help.

**UPDATE:**
Even booting with the older 4.15.0-101-generic kernel I'm having the same problems.

**UPDATE2**
AFAICS somewhat solved with another update from today 20 May. Now disabling/enabling Wifi makes it workable, but the problem does recur at irregular intervals.

Comment: How about drivers? I know of [other questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049307/slow-wifi-with-ubuntu-18-04-and-intel-dual-band-wireless-ac-3168) like this, which were resolved with drivers.

Comment: Thanks, there are more reports of similar problem with the 5.3 kernel. Thing here, it was working fine, it is a sudden regression. Not sure which update caused it. Or could it be a hardware failure?

Comment: I cannot speculate on the hardware failure - it's possible, but I cannot confirm. I see a software update helped alleviate this, so I would infer this a bug.